# PHP Initialising strings as boolean first

Tags: php, optimization

I'm in the habit of initialising variables in PHP to false and then applying whatever (string, boolean, float) value to it later.

Which would you reckon is better?

```
$name = false;
if (condition == true) {
    $name = $something_else;
}

if ($name) {  …do something…  }
```

**vs.**

```
$name ='';
if (condition == true) {
    $name = $something_else;
}

if (!empty($name)) {  …do something…  }
```

Which would you reckon can possibly give better performance? Which method would you use?

Comment: This question belongs to codereview site of stacks

Comment: I feel you should change your habbit. If you want to initialize them as something, initialize them as `null`. False is actually a value with meaning, this could cause issues here and then. (just my 2 cents, if i offend, it was not intended)

Comment: @SureshKamrushi Why ? This Q is an excellent one, perfectly fitting for SO.

Comment: I can't imagine there would be a significant difference in performance. But certainly semantically null would be better than false. Depending on the context, an empty string may also be appropriate.

Comment: Never check `empty` on a variable guaranteed to exist! [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Answer (score 5):

At first glance - your `$condition==true` is pointless since `$condition` is well enough.

Second - if you're not sure what type will be variable, but you want to initialize it (that is - indeed - a good habit), use `null` - since `false` points to certain data type - bool data type, while it's not correct and person who reads your code may be confused.

Answer (score 3):

Both values `''` as `false` have meaning.

I would suggest using `null` as the default value. Since that actually does not (and should not) 'mean' anything.

This will also allow you to test `is_null($var)` to make sure something actually set a value to your variable.

Comment: Well, `null` *means* "none of the above" or "no value" or "nothing"... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here [Basic php benchmarks](http://www.phpbench.com/).I usually use null. A must know [here](http://itslennysfault.com/php-isset-vs-empty) also.

Answer (score 0):

Well what I think giving it Boolean value is better. It won't make much difference when you compare code running on a very powerful system.

but when it comes to system performance then it all depends upon the size of datatype you are using. boolean uses 1 bit of data. So, it is more convenient to use, and faster also.

Adding to other answers, better use null.

Answer (score 0):

I think irrespective of your above two choices the performance of an if-statement depends on whether its condition has a predictable pattern i.e. **BRANCH PREDICTION**. If the condition is always true or always false,i.e. if it is predictable, the branch prediction logic in the processor will pick up the pattern. On the other hand, if the processor cant predict the condition than it may affect the performance.

when talking about your code,the optimize one i can think of is

```
  $name = false;// i dont think u should predeclare the 'name' variable 
   //as it is dependent on the if condition.so if the condition fails then
  //the $name will be   of no use. 
    if (condition) {
        $name = $something_else;
    }

    if ($name) //this condition will only be executed 
   // when $name is true so why predeclare $name.
    {  …do something…  
    }
```